# Selection returning max,min and avg

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python

I'm new on RethinkDB and need to return min , max and avg of "value" by grouping on "id", here's an example of my Json :

```
{
  "mycontent": [
    {
      "id": "000000000011",
      "value": "300"
    },
    {
      "id": "000000000012",
      "value": "500"
    },
    {
      "id": "000000000011",
      "value": "700"
    },
    {
      "id": "000000000013",
      "value": "200"
    },
    {
      "id": "000000000011",
      "value": "950"
    },
    {
      "id": "000000000012",
      "value": "150"
    }
  ]
}
```

I find some problem understanding how to do that using RethinkDB logic.
Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `()` to get the value out of `mycontent` and `group` by id. One issue is your data is string, hence you need to convert to number for `avg` to works.

something like this:

```
r.expr({
  "mycontent": [
    {
      "id": "000000000011",
      "value": "300"
    },
    {
      "id": "000000000012",
      "value": "500"
    },
    {
      "id": "000000000011",
      "value": "700"
    },
    {
      "id": "000000000013",
      "value": "200"
    },
    {
      "id": "000000000011",
      "value": "950"
    },
    {
      "id": "000000000012",
      "value": "150"
    }
  ]
})('mycontent')
  .merge({value: r.row('value').coerceTo('number')})
  .group('id')
  .avg('value')
```

Comment: Thank you kureikain , but i need to get the AVG, Max and Min of my datas, i tried something like .group('id').avg('value').max(value).min(value) but i think i didn't yet understood how it works.